# Rserve installation on macos 11 Big Sur

Tags: r, macos-big-sur, rserve

I have upgraded mac OS to version 11 - Big Sur. Since then, I'm not able to install Rserve package. I've tried the installation using the following command:

`install.packages('Rserve',,'http://www.rforge.net/')`

Unfortunately, the result is a non-zero exit and the output contain the following messages:

> configure error: R was configured without --enable-R-shlib or --enable-R-static-lib```
> *** Rserve requires R (shared or static) library.
> *** Pleae install R library or compile R with either --enable-R-shlib
> or --enable-R-static-lib support.
> Alternatively use --without-server if you wish to build only Rserve client.

No Rserve client is totally no option for me. Do you have any suggestions what can I do go get Rserve installed?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How did you install R? You should reinstall it, if you haven't already.

Comment: I've already reinstalled it. I've also tried installing older version (3.3.3). The problem remains the same. Generally, I've installed R using pkg installer from r-project.org

Comment: If the problem is to do with compiling from source, you could try this workaround I've used to solve similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340